# Display Feedback "Stutters" When Moving Features

Tags: arcobjects, c#, features, ux

I have a custom tool for moving features that implements IDisplayFeedback and geometry-specific CoClasses to show the user where they are moving the feature.

```
    IMovePolygonFeedback polygonFeedback;
    bool feedbackStarted;

    public override void OnMouseDown(int Button, int Shift, int X, int Y)
    {
        feedbackStarted = false;
        
        //A BUNCH OF STUFF HERE TO SELECT A FEATURE ON MOUSEDOWN

        geometry = feature.Shape;
        
        polygonFeedback = new MovePolygonFeedbackClass();
        polygonFeedback.Display = doc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay;
        polygonFeedback.Start(geometry as IPolygon, doc.CurrentLocation);
        feedbackStarted = true;
    }

    public override void OnMouseMove(int Button, int Shift, int X, int Y)
    {
        IPoint point = doc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y);
        if (polygonFeedback != null && feedbackStarted)
            polygonFeedback.MoveTo(point);
    }
```

What sometimes happens when the mousedown and mousemove happen quickly is that the feedback display stutters for a second, leaving a (what I assume to be) graphic, then continues on with a new graphic moving around with the mouse until mouseup.  Looks like this:

[image]

At mouseup I change the feature shape to the new position and store the feature.  I union the original feature extent with the new feature extent and pass that envelope to a partial refresh.  Problem is sometimes parts of the "stutter" aren't in that envelope so I get dangly bits:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzkhm.png

I'm trying to avoid straight refreshes but these dangly bits are not pretty and don't go away until a refresh happens (forced by user or move/pan, etc.)

Questions:

1. Does anybody know why the "stutter" is happening and how can I prevent it?
2. Is there a way to partially refresh the dangly bits?
3. What is the feedback?  Is it a graphic?  Can I trap it during the onmove to add it to the partial refresh envelope?
4. Is there an infinitely better way to do this that I'm mising?

Answer (score 1):

You might try calling [`IScreenDisplay.UpdateWindow()`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000002z2000000) within your `OnMouseMove` method, may not work at all but it's an easy thing to try.